# Java, JOptionPane cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

I get this error when i make run my "JOptionPane.showOptionDialog" command. I have followed the steps on the Oracle toturial page, but this one just won't go. I can add my imports if it's needed, but the list is pretty long.

[Picture of the error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AXF5.png)

```
Object[] options = {"Ja", "Nej"}; //the values i want my buttons to have
    int test = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, //should make the panel, BlueJ marks showOptionDialog as the problem
        spm, //this is a variable i define earlier in the code. Won't be a problem
        "TestTwo", //the name of the window
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, //To be honest, idk what this do
        null, //To be honest, idk what this do
        options, //implements the values from the top
        options[0]); //Don't really know this one either
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing argument `MessageType`.

These are the arguments an option pane requires:

`JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(parentComponent, message, title, optionType, messageType, icon, options, initialValue)`

```
Object[] options = {"Ja", "Nej"};
    int test = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
        spm,
        "TestTwo", //the name of the window
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, //Type of options, those two buttons at bottom of box
        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, //The JOptionPane type
        null, //Icon to be applied to dialog
        options, //implements the values from the top
        options[0]); //The default selected component when dialog opens
```

Comment: F*ck, that was obvious. Thank you very much.